# R: read.table with colClasses gives Error in integer(n) : vector size cannot be NA/NaN

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I'm trying to read a simple dataframe into R using `read.table`. While reading the table I want to specify that the first 3 columns are of type character, while the remaining 4 columns are of type numeric.

I'm specifying the column types to prevent R from dropping the leading 0's in columns 2 and 3, as they're required for DB lookups. Here's what I'm using:

```
df.img <- read.table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/46dde948263136d0b52be1575232a83e/raw/80f14650e4f4b9ef38a5dec3f5bbb8c62954ee59/match-stats.tsv',
            sep='\t',
            colClasses=c(replicate('character', 3), replicate('numeric', 4)))
```

This returns:

> Error in integer(n) : vector size cannot be NA/NaN
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In integer(n) : NAs introduced by coercion

Does anyone know how I can update my `read.table` command to correctly read in my columns with the desired types? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I should have been using `rep()`:

```
df.img <- read.table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/46dde948263136d0b52be1575232a83e/raw/80f14650e4f4b9ef38a5dec3f5bbb8c62954ee59/match-stats.tsv',
                     sep='\t',
                     colClasses=c(rep('character', 3), rep('numeric', 4)))
```